# How do I get the sum of values of a variable to a textview on button click set in the recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that display the product name, selling price and a remove textview.
[image]

I want to display the total price in a POS fragment in a textview when I click the add button
[image]

This is what I have done

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getProduct(mBarcode.getText().toString());
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do {
                        mBarcode.setText("");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String id = cursor.getString(0);
                        String barcode = cursor.getString(1);
                        String name = cursor.getString(2);
                        String oprice = cursor.getString(3);
                        String sprice = cursor.getString(4);
                        String date = cursor.getString(5);
                        double converter = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(sprice));
                        double u_price = 0;
                        u_price += converter;
                        total.setText(String.valueOf(u_price));
                        mainList.add(new Products(Integer.parseInt(id),1, barcode, name, "Total: K"+sprice, oprice, date));
                    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

When I click on the button, am only getting the single value of `u_price` and not the total price.
This my onBindViewHolder in the POSAdapter

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull POSAdapter.ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Products products = mainList.get(position);
        holder.item.setText(products.getName());
        holder.price.setText(products.getSprice());
        holder.remove.setText("X");
        holder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mainList.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
        });
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is when you initialize the variable u_price with a 0,
every time you initialize the 0 the result will be 0+converted value;
just move the

```
double u_price = 0;
```

to the out of the ClickListener;

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            double u_price = 0;
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getProduct(mBarcode.getText().toString());
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do {
                        mBarcode.setText("");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String id = cursor.getString(0);
                        String barcode = cursor.getString(1);
                        String name = cursor.getString(2);
                        String oprice = cursor.getString(3);
                        String sprice = cursor.getString(4);
                        String date = cursor.getString(5);
                        double converter = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(sprice));
                        u_price += converter;
                        total.setText(String.valueOf(u_price));
                        mainList.add(new Products(Integer.parseInt(id),1, barcode, name, "Total: K"+sprice, oprice, date));
                    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```